# Is it enough to compute the estimated cost function?

Tags: cross-validation, svm, matlab, model-evaluation

I am using `ls-svm lab` toolbox in `matlab` for `regression` analysis. Here is the code:

```
%%
%read from file
filename='datasample500.xlsx';
data=xlsread(filename);
input=data(:,1:12);
oilOut=data(:,13);
waterOut=data(:,14);
liqOut=data(:,15);
%gasOut=data(:,11);

%%
%train model
type = 'function estimation';
kernel='RBF_kernel';
fold=10;
[gam,sig2,cost] = tunelssvm({input,oilOut,type,[],      
                            [],kernel},'simplex','crossvalidatelssvm',{fold,'mse'});
[alpha,b] = trainlssvm({input,oilOut,type,gam,sig2,kernel});
```

The function tutorial for `tunelssvm` states:

> Tune the tuning parameters of the model with respect to the given
>   performance measure

to sum up its explanation:

> First, for every kernel, first Coupled Simulated Annealing (CSA)
>   determines suitable starting points for every method..... costfun gives an
>   estimate of the performance of the model Possible functions for
>   costfun are crossvalidatelssvm, leaveoneoutlssvm, rcrossvalidatelssvm
>   and gcrossvalidatelssvm.

Actually, the `tunelssvm` function estimates the regularization parameter `gam` and the squared kernel parameter `sig2`. It also computes the ***estimation*** of cost function( `mse` in here).

I want to use `cross validation` method to avoid overfitting problems. There is also a notification in `crossvalidation` function as below:

> CAUTION!! Use this function only to obtain the value of the
>   crossvalidation score function given the tuning parameters. Do not use
>   this function together with tunelssvm, but use crossvalidatelssvm
>   instead. The latter is a faster implementation which uses previously
>   computed results.

As you see I used `crossvalidatelssvm` in the `tunelssvm`.

My question is that if this **estimated cost function** in `tunelssvm` is a good representative of the **exact cost function** to report?

is not it needed to use `cross validation` through the process of `training model` instead of in the process of `parameter estimation` in `tunelssvm`?

the tutorial for ls-svm lab is available in [here](http://www.esat.kuleuven.be/sista/lssvmlab/downloads/tutorialv1_8.pdf).